# SharePoint Online Gear menu changed recently

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-dev-pnp

Recently I see the gear icon menu has been changed.

Is this something I can revert to old?
Can someone help me in getting the official announcements on this by Microsoft?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This change is only in modern pages it seems, and while I can't site a reference, I can pretty well tell you that there is no supported way for you to do anything about it, any more than you can do anything else to change modern pages (other than revert to classic pages, if that's an option).  That's not counting things like you can do a header, footer, maybe colorize a cell in a view, but there's no supported way for you to color outside the box (i.e. change the stuff Microsoft renders).

I can't say that I've seen an official announcement about it, but over the years they've moved the gear icon left, they moved the gear icon right, they've done the hokey pokey and they've moved it all about, and most of the time without any official announcement. And if you complain about it, they point you to [Who Moved My Cheese](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/who-moved-my-cheese/fgqpf3h0cjt6?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab), which is a thinly veiled insult that says "it's not us, it's you."

Terminating rant now...